# R: Replacing X-Axis Logarithm Labels with Original Values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 100, 100))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 1000, 1000))
df3 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 10000, 10000))
df = data.frame(rbind(df1,df2, df3))
df$id = 1:nrow(df)
df$x1 = log(df$x1)


ggplot(df, aes(x1)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16, by = 1))
```

[image]
**My Question:** Now, I am trying to replace the logarithm x-axis labels with the original values - while keeping the original graph.

Here is my attempt:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x1)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16, by = 1),
                       labels = function(breaks) round(exp(breaks)))
```

[image]

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest is to not log transform before plotting, and use `scale_x_log10()`

Comment: What do you mean by "original values"? It looks like that's what's being done, but perhaps you wanted a break at 100 instead of 148, for example? Perhaps you want something like `breaks = log(10^(1:5))`...

Comment: How do you want to deal with all the <0 x1 values that are generated in this example? They are NA when log-transformed, so excluded from the plotting. `scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans)` is a more "inclusive" approach but is likely less familiar to many audiences, and will look weird for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_log10`. You'll need to exponentiate the log-transformed variable (or just don't log it in the first place)

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 100, 100))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 1000, 1000))
df3 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 10000, 10000))
df = data.frame(rbind(df1,df2, df3))
df$id = 1:nrow(df)

ggplot(df, aes(x1)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_log10("x1", breaks = 10^(0:6))
```

[image]

Note that however you carry out the log transform, any values less than or equal to zero will be `NaN` and therefore removed from the plot. If you want to include the negative values, you can use a pseudo-log transform instead:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x1)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 60) +
  scale_x_continuous("x1", trans = "pseudo_log", 
                     breaks = c(-(10^(1:6)), 0, 10^(1:6)))
```

[image]

Comment: What would you recommend as best practice for dealing with the values < 0 that occur in most runs of this random data?

Comment: @JonSpring if it's a genuine log scale, I'd probably just ditch those values, but you can use pseudo-log instead depending on the use case. See my edit.